# Angular Error TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, httpclient

So something strange is going on, I am making an HTTP get in my service but I am getting an error, the strange thing is it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, but for the past 24 hours it's not been working anymore. Code for a service call and subscription are below. and then also the error.

category.service.ts

```
getcategory(id) {
    const url = `${this.localUrl}category/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<CategoryResponse>(url)
        .pipe( catchError(this.errorHandler) );
}
```

Error Handler

```
errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }

      // return an observable with a user-facing error message
     return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

add-edit-category.component.ts

```
if (this.router.url.indexOf('edit') >= 0) {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
            this.categoryService.getcategory(params.get('id'))))
        .subscribe(results => {
            this.category = results.category;

            this.categoryNameControl.setValue(this.category.categoryName);
            this.categoryDescriptionControl.setValue(this.category.categoryDescription);
            console.log("I am edit", Object.keys(config))
            console.log("TEst again", this.category)
        }, error => {
            console.log("Error", error)
        });
}
```

Error

```
Error TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
at Object.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js.exports.subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:42)
at Object.subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:7)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:103)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/switchMap.js.SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:96)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:103)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:81)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/BehaviorSubject.js.BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:26)
at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:176)
at BehaviorSubject.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:96)
```

Comment: Can you show what `this.errorHandler` does  ?

Comment: @Mium I have added the error handler

Comment: Is your question still open ?

Comment: hey guys I found the solution to the issue I was import the wrong rxjs. Should I post the answer or its irrevelant as this was just a minute import issue

Comment: It depends on the error. Is it something that might systematically happen to others ? If not, I think it's better to delete this question.

Comment: @madjaoue Yeah Im sure someone would definitely import the wrong library and be frustrated trying to find out what it was.

Comment: So you imported rxjs5 instead of rxjs 6 ?